# Tool to auto generate Class fields of 'View' type from layout XML?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, eclipse-plugin

I'm using eclipse Android SDK, as i can see there are code generator tool builtin to generate getters() and setters() from the current class. I'd like to know if there are such tools to auto generate Android View class instances, into the current class from a given layout. Possibly auto instantiate them in the onCreate() call back.

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".Main" >

        <TextView
            style="@style/Divider_Title"
            android:text="@string/pi_name_title" />

        <View style="@style/Divider" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_firstname"
            style="@style/EditText"
            android:hint="@string/pi_first_name"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_lastname"
            style="@style/EditText"
            android:hint="@string/pi_last_name"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />
            ....
```

would generate for an already existing class SignIn

```
public class SignIn extends FragmentActivity  {

    private EditText et_firstname;
    private EditText et_lastname; 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration);

        et_firstname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_firstname);
        et_lastname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_lastname);
                ...

    }
```

Comment: Which SDK version are you using?

Comment: Build: v22.0.1-685705

Comment: If you meant the API level SDK 17.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the following [link](http://tmorcinek.wordpress.com/2011/11/30/eclipse-plugin-for-automatic-generation-of-activity-code-from-xml-layout-file/)

Plugin from the link has been refactored and updated with new functionality (basically rewritten). Now can generate Activity, Fragment, Adapter based on xml layout. Can also generate Menu related code (handling actions) for xml menu files. And has editable templates, so the user has more control on the generated data.

http://tmorcinek.github.io/android-codegenerator-plugin-eclipse/

Comment: If you have an answer, please add the necessary information in the post itself, rather than depending on the link to answer the question. Link only answers are discouraged in stackoverflow.

Comment: @Krishnabhadra it was not feasible for me to post the entire answer in  here with the desired information that's why i mentioned it in a link..thanks for letting me know..will keep it in mind

Answer (score 1):

We developed a tool that which creates view variables automatically, set custom fonts and listeners easily. You can use [this](http://lab.mobillium.com/xml2class/step1)